# Differential equation with $f(x)$ and $f(x+y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can a differential equation of the following form:

$$ a f'(x) + b f(x) + c f(x + y) =0 $$

be solved (for $a,b,c, y \in \mathbb{R}$ some constants) ?

Comment: Have you learned Laplace transforms?

Comment: No, haven't encountered it yet.

Comment: These are still solved by exponential functions, just like $af'(x)+bf(x)=0$, as far as I can tell.

Comment: In what context did you come across this equation? As you're talking about a solution, do you already know whether a solution exists?

Comment: @flawr, appeared in an economic model I set up. $f(x)$ is a distribution function I'm trying to find, and $f(x+y)$ is the probability that a random draw is below $x+y$. Haven't yet proven whether a solution exists at all.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: Assume a form of solution $f(x) = e^{\alpha x}$  Then plug into the equation to get $a\alpha +b+ce^{\alpha y}=0$.  So you have an equation that can be solved, in principle, for $\alpha$.  How to do it in practice?  I'm not seeing it.

Comment: It looks like a job for the [Lambert W function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).